# If () statements in Js

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

Here I have a search component the thing I am trying to achieve is his. How would I approach where there is no item in the array, should I make an if statement, or what should I do to achieve this. Help would be really appreciated. Thanks

```
import React,{useState, useEffect, useRef, useContext}from 'react'
import {FaSearch} from 'react-icons/fa'
import { 
    Link, useHistory
  } from "react-router-dom";
import { BookContext } from '../../context/books';
import SearchBooks from './SearchBooks';

const Search = () => {

  const {data}= useContext(BookContext)
  const [searchValue, setSearchValue] = React.useState('');
  const history= useHistory()

  function filterBooks(book) {
    console.log(book);
    if(!searchValue.length ) return book.bookName > 10
    if (!searchValue.length  ) return false;
    return book.bookName?.toLowerCase().includes(searchValue.toLowerCase());
  }


    return (
        <div className='search__cont' >   
           <SearchBooks searchValue={searchValue} setSearchValue={setSearchValue 
 }/>     

              {Object.keys(data).filter(filterBooks).length === 0 &&(
               <div>
                <h3>Book not found</h3>
               </div>
                )}
           {Object.keys(data)
             .map((key) => data[key])
             .reduce((acc, curr) => acc.concat(curr), [])
             .filter(filterBooks)
             .map((book) => {          
             return (
             <>       
              <div  className='search__books'
                onClick={() => {
                  history.push("/book/id", { book }); setSearchValue('')
                }}
               >            
                {" "}
                {book.bookName}{" "}
              </div>            
            </>
          );
        })}
           </div>
    )
}

export default Search
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
return book.length === 0 ? (
    <div>
      <h1>No items has been found </h1>
    </div>
) : (
    <div className='search__books'> ... </div>
);
```

This is called a [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator). It'll return the first part if the condition is true, else it will return the second part.

Edit: As you need a more full example, something along the lines of this:

```
function filter() {
  const books = Object.keys(data)
    .map((key) => data[key])
    .reduce((acc, curr) => acc.concat(curr), [])
    .filter(...);

  return books.length ?
    books.map((book) => (
      <div className='search__books' onClick={() => {
        history.push("/book/id", { book });
        setSearchValue('')
      }}>            
        {" "}
        {book.bookName}{" "}
      </div>            
    ))) : (
      <div>
        <h1>No items has been found </h1>
      </div>
    );
}

return (
  <div className='search__cont' >   
    <SearchBooks searchValue={searchValue} setSearchValue={setSearchValue }/>          
    {filter()}
  </div>
)
```

Comment: well I am getting a book is not defined

Comment: Well that's because `book` isn't in scope. Not in scope in your example either.

Comment: I know it is not in the scope, how should I make into the scope

Comment: Updated the answer, hopefully that's giving you a more complete picture.

Comment: updated the question so you can see mine  approach

Comment: You shouldn't do that as you'll be executing the second block of code no matter what. Use a ternary, like I suggested.

Comment: It is displaying in on the render ```<h1>No items has been found </h1>```

Comment: Sure, it'll display, but your solution means you're executing the `Object.keys...` no matter what because you're not properly using conditionals.

Comment: I did in the other way, do you know how could I set so the search value is displaying max of 10 items, BCS right now if I type the let's say A it is displaying bunch of items

Comment: let's say could this approach work ```if(!searchValue.length ) return book.bookName > 10``` in the filterBook function

Comment: You'd just need to paginate. Create a `page` state value, then do a slice upon the array. `array.slice((page - 1) * limit, page * limit)`.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/books-ohqo3?file=/src/Search.js he is the link to my search. But I do not see how would I implement your logic into this, anyway I am going to give the right answer even if you don't do it, bcs yo are a good guy